# Link checker not working for cck fields?

Tags: 7, entities

Link checker is not working for entity fields. It is only checking the body text, but not the text provided in a field. I created text field, but it is not considered when reporting the broken links. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: for which field type(text/term reference/link) its not working? also which version of Drupal you're using?

Comment: Astha -- Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. Support your questions with errors screenshots etc. Always provide details like Mathan said above...

Comment: I am using Drupal7 and my field type is text.